# C++ : use of deleted function

Tags: c++

I am doing circles around trying to fix this but still no luck. I am sure I am confusing basic C++ stuff so need your help.

```
class TypeA {
  TypeA( const int id ) ;
  TypeA() ;
  private :
     int n_id ;
}
```

then on my class B**.h**

```
class TypeB :
   TypeB( const int x , const int y ) ;
   TypeB( const int x , const int y , const TypeA& a) ;
   private :
       int _x ;
       int _y ;
       TypeA _a ;
```

I am having issues on my second constructor.

**.cpp**

```
TypeB( const int x , const int y , const TypeA& a) : _x( x) , _y(y) {
   _a = a ;
}
```

and I am getting this error :

```
use of deleted function TypeA::operator=(TypeA&)
note : TypeA::operator=(TypeA&) is implicity deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed
class TypeA
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Edit :**
I tried this :

```
TypeB( const int x , const int y , const TypeA& a) : _x( x) , _y(y) , _a(a) { }
```

and now error becomes :

```
use of deleted function TypeA&  _a(a)
note : TypeA is implicity deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed. 
class TypeA
```

does that mean that the problem then lies into my default constructor of my typeA ?

Comment: Hint: you didn't use assignment for `_x` or `_y`, but you use it for `_a`.

Comment: I am trying to put in my constructor list - but apparently I am doing it wrong. Tried '_a( a )' but didn't work either.

Comment: @ghostrider "Didn't work either" isn't helpful, what error did you get when you did that?

Comment: let me update my answer.

Comment: your constructors are private, is that intentional? anyway, [it appears to be working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3abbf056deb7645f)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9182df02695cbf86) by adding `public:` where it should be present.

Comment: @Borgleader It's because you (and sp2danny) provide an instance of the constructors: `TypeA() : n_id(0) {}` against `TypeA() ;` in the OP's code.

Comment: @TripeHound missing that should result in a linker error, rather than an implicitly deleted assignment operator

Comment: @sp2danny The code you pasted, without the `: n_id(0) {}` does indeed give linker errors for me, not what the OP gets, but that appears to be the only significant difference between your code and theirs.

Comment: @TripeHound Exactly, that is why we need an MCVE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your TypeA class a constructor (even default if you want) and change your type B constructor. Remember that class attributes and functions are private by default

Full answer :

```
class TypeA {
public :
  TypeA() = default;
  ~TypeA() = default;
private :
  int n_id ;
};

class TypeB {
public :
    TypeB(const int x ,const int y);
    TypeB(const int x ,const int y ,const TypeA& a);
    ~TypeB() = default;
private :
    int _x;
    int _y;
    TypeA _a; 
};

TypeB::TypeB(const int x ,const int y ,const TypeA& a) : _x( x) , _y(y), _a(a) {
}

int main(void)
{
    TypeA test;
    TypeB hello(10, 10, test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define 'public' your constructors!!! If you don't write 'public', by default, everything is private in a class:

```
class TypeA {
  public:  // <--- you need this!!!
  TypeA( const int id ) ;
  TypeA() ;
  private :
 int n_id ;
};
```

And don't pass 'const int id', only 'int id'. 'id' is passing by value, so why do you need it to be const?

Comment: Pretty straightforward when you see const, you know it won't be changed in the function

Comment: @rak007 Why should the caller care if the callee modifies theyre own copy of the int inside the function? That's an impl detail. While I tend to leave it out, I can understand why someone would leave it in.